# ASP.NET Background Thread blocking page access

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, lucene.net

I have a (very old but still maintained) website built on .NET WebForms.

Recently I had the need to add a task/operation that, upon click on a button, initiates a background thread that updates a bunch of different stuff:
1 - Integrate with an outside API to fetch information and write it into the database
2 - Update a search index built on Lucene

The code, on what we call the Settings page (Setting.aspx) looks something like this:

```
protected void btnForcePartialSync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;

    string logLocation = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(VirtualPathUtility.AppendTrailingSlash(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SyncLogsLocation"]) + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PartialSyncLogName"]);

    if (File.Exists(logLocation))
        Renamefile(logLocation);

    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(logLocation);

    DateTime end = DateTime.UtcNow;
    DateTime start;

    if (button.Equals(btnDoPartialSyncMonth))
        start = end.AddMonths(-1);
    else
        start = end.AddHours(-24);

    HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
    ThreadStart starter = () => { PopulateCv.ForcePartialSync(sw, start, end); };
    starter += () => {
        HttpContext.Current = ctx;
        CacheService.ClearCache(CacheService.WORKS_COUNT_CACHE_KEY);
        int CvCount = DataAccess.Cv.Cv.GetActiveCvs().Count;
        CacheService.Add(CacheService.WORKS_COUNT_CACHE_KEY, CurriculumCount);
        CVSearchIndex.BuildIndex();
        FillContentsIndexInfo();
    };

    Thread t = new Thread(starter) { IsBackground = true };
    t.Start();
}
```

This process, as expected, takes some time to complete since the `CVSearchIndex.BuildIndex();` operation is very long (over 10 minutes). Everything is fine up until here.

It *seems* to work nicely, and I can still use the site and navigate to a different page, e.g. Homepage while the operation completes.

**However** once I try to navigate back into the Settings page, it simply will not load until the thread ends (when it's done building the search index).

This is not the behaviour I was expecting. How can I solve this without substantial changes to the current code?
Can I make the navigation to this page not block while the search index is being built?

Best Regards.

Comment: `starter +=` ?? You have a multicast delegate as your thread worker? Why?

Comment: It's a very weird way to execute 2 pieces of code in succession.

Comment: Does the settings page access the lucene index that is getting build in any way?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably blocking due to Session mutex.  Try adding the following to the page (aspx) `<%@ Page EnableSessionState="true|false|ReadOnly" %>` (false or ReadOnly)

Alternatively, if it's just a fire and forget operation, you could set it up as a scheduled task, and then fire it off manually from your method, allowing the method to end immediately (running the job in the background)